# When nested bottom navigation, getting some issue in android

Tags: android

I have two menus, bottomMenu-1, bottomMenu-2.

bottomMenu-1 has nested fragments. bottomMenu-1-A, bottomMenu-1-B (A -> B).
The scenario is like below.

1. I navigate bottomMenu-1(default screen) A -> bottomMenu-1-B
2. click bottomMenu-2.
3. click bottomMenu-1 again, then I get some issue.

The bottomMenu-1-B Screen is displayed as bottomMenu-2 is selected.
I want that bottomMenu-1 is selected but it doesn't.
I don't understand Why this is happening.
here is my navgation graph.

*Activity Setting*

```
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(binding.mainContainer.id) as NavHostFragment
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navHostFragment.navController)
```

*Navigation Graph*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

// BottomMenu-1-A
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.my.test.main.home.main_page.MainPageFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_main_to_uploaded_music"
            app:destination="@id/uploadedMusicFragment"
            />
    </fragment>

// BottomMenu-1-B
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/uploadedMusicFragment"
        android:name="com.my.test.main.home.uploaded_music.UploadedMusicFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_uploaded_music" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_uploaded_music_to_main"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment"
            />
    </fragment>

// BottomMenu-2
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myPlayListFragment"
        android:name="com.my.test.main.myplaylist.MyPlayListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_playlist" >
    </fragment>


</navigation>
```

Please Let me understand this.